# Why following Java code behaves like a repeated loop?

Tags: java

Im trying to draw an image onto itself once.But it kinda behaves like loop and image is drawn many times over and over. Why it is behaving like a loop?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;

 public class Swapper{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws 
 IOException {
    try{
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("picture2.jpg"));

Graphics g = img.getGraphics();

g.drawImage(img,100,100, null);

File file = new File("aaaimage3.png");
    ImageIO.write(img,"png", file);
}

catch(IOException e){}
}
}
```

For example, with this input:

[image: Standard TV test picture]

You get this output:

[image: Image tunneling effect with repeated copies]

Comment: This, `catch(IOException e){}`, isn't in your real code, is it?

Comment: Think about what might happen depending on how the drawing is implemented: if you start drawing the image at 100x100 onto itself when you get to 100x100 in the now-new-image you’ll get the start of the new image you started drawing on to it, which now contains the start of the original image. At 200x200 the same thing, etc. If it’s a row-by-row/column-by-column draw it’s what I’d expect, not that it’d be the only way it could be done.

Comment: To get the desired behaviour, create another `BufferredImage` and draw twice on that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing the image from itself and to itself. This means that the image is being modified as it's being copied, and since it copies a section at a time, it causes this effect.

For example, imagine you are trying to copy this string onto itself at an offset of 2, and you can move 4 characters at a time:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

First you read characters 0-3 (`abcd`) and copy them into the string giving:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
^---
  v---
ababcdghijklmnop
```

Then you copy the characters 4-7 (cdgh) and copy them into the next spots:

```
ababcdghijklmnop
    ^---
      v---
ababcdcdghklmnop
```

Then you copy the 8-11:

```
ababcdcdghklmnop
        ^---
          v---
ababcdcdghghklop
```

And so on. As you can see, due to only copying a certain buffer at a time from a source that keeps changing, you end up with repeated patterns like `ababcdcdghgh..`